# Processing function and parameters

Tags: function, parameters, processing

I am having trouble coming up with a program that draws a ball on the screen using a function including values in the parameter and then making it move across at a constant speed. As you can tell I am a noob and don't quite understand parameters.
Here is what I have so far.

```
float BallXLoc;
float BallYLoc;

float ballDiam = 40;
float ballRadius = 40;
float xSpeed = 1;

void setup() {
size(400, 400);
}

void draw() {
  drawBall(BallXLoc, BallYLoc);
  BallXLoc = BallXLoc + xSpeed;
}

void drawBall(float xPos, float yPos) {
  ellipse(200, 200, ballDiam, ballRadius);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a little off. The parameters you pass in the `drawBall()` function should be actually used in the function to position the ellipse. 
Replace this line of code:

```
ellipse(200, 200, ballDiam, ballRadius);
```

With this:

```
ellipse(xPos, yPos, ballDiam, ballRadius);
```

In addition, your convention is a little off. I would define `BallXLoc`, and `BallYLoc` in the top so your ellipse has a starting point. In addition, you should define the types of your variables as `ints`, as they are whole numbers.
You'll have this:

```
int BallXLoc = 100;
int BallYLoc = 100;

int ballDiam = 40;
int ballRadius = 40;
int xSpeed = 1;

void setup() {
size(400, 400);
}

void draw() {
  background(211, 211, 211);
  drawBall(BallXLoc, BallYLoc);
  BallXLoc = BallXLoc + xSpeed;
}

void drawBall(int xPos, int yPos) {
  ellipse(xPos, yPos, ballDiam, ballRadius);
}
```

I added this line of code:

```
background(211, 211, 211);
```

To prevent the circle from making a pathway. The default background for processing is *light gray (211, 211, 211)*, and each time, the background is cleared and the ellipse is redrawn with a new position. You will see the ellipse move at a constant rate across the screen.